# Behat incompatible with Symfony3?

Tags: php, behat, symfony

I'm using Symfony3 for a project and I got this error when I try to add the behat package.

Seems like its not possible to use behat with Symfony3 yet due do the problem with yaml parser version incompatibilities.

Is it so or has someone come with a workaround?

```
composer require behat/behat --dev
```

> Problem 1
>       - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.0.1
>       - behat/behat v3.0.0 requires symfony/yaml ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No official release yet, but last `dev-master` version has symfony3 compatibility. [there is a candidate release](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/releases/tag/v3.1.0rc1) . You can install behat version with `v3.1.0rc1` tag.

```
composer.phar require behat/behat='v3.1.0rc1'
```

Or install the last `dev-master` which includes last release candidates